# Google chart - missing column and repeatig x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create column chart but I have got a problem with missing column for year 2009 and repeating x-axis labels.

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            [
            {label: "year", type: "number", format: "none"},
            {label: "performance 1", type: "number", format: "none"},
          {label: "performance 2", type: "number", format: "none"},
        ],
        ["2008", 4, 7],
        ["2009", 10, 12],
        ["2010", 15, 18],
        ["2011", 3, 20],
        ["2012", 5, 4]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title:"Testing chart - column",
      hAxis:{
        format:"####",
        title:"",
        viewWindow:{
          min:"2009"
        },
        showTextEvery:"1"
      },
      vAxis:{
        title:""
      },
        colors: ["#805e59","#e6d2cf"]
   };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

[image]

JSFiddle can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/8rdc4u1L/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is using --> `type: "number"` -- for the x-axis

in my experience column / bar charts work better with --> `type: "string"`

which is actually what you're providing anyway --> `["2008", 4, 7],`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [{
      label: "year",
      type: "string",
      format: "none"
    },
     {
       label: "performance 1",
       type: "number",
       format: "none"
     },
     {
       label: "performance 2",
       type: "number",
       format: "none"
     },
    ],
    ["2008", 4, 7],
    ["2009", 10, 12],
    ["2010", 15, 18],
    ["2011", 3, 20],
    ["2012", 5, 4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: "Testing chart - column",
    colors: ["#805e59", "#e6d2cf"]
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

note: this will also avoid the problem with the tooltip from the other question...

---

**EDIT**

if you want to use numbers for x-axis,
recommend using the `ticks` option to control which labels appear...

```
ticks: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012]
```

to fill `ticks` dynamically, use data table / view method --> `getDistinctValues`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [{
        label: "year",
        type: "number",
        format: "none"
      },
      {
        label: "performance 1",
        type: "number",
        format: "none"
      },
      {
        label: "performance 2",
        type: "number",
        format: "none"
      },
    ],
    ["2008", 4, 7],
    ["2009", 10, 12],
    ["2010", 15, 18],
    ["2011", 3, 20],
    ["2012", 5, 4]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 0,
    test: function (value) {
      return (value > 2008);
    }
  }]));

  var options = {
    title: "Testing chart - column",
    hAxis: {
      ticks: view.getDistinctValues(0),
      format: "####",
      title: "",
      showTextEvery: "1"
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: ""
    },
    colors: ["#805e59", "#e6d2cf"]
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks,  but unfortunately I cannot use type string because sometimes I wanna show only statistic for year >2010...

Comment: yes, I want to show everything that is equal or bigger than 2009 and again yes I am using dataview. Is it a problem with that?

Comment: I simplified my question. Basically, I am developing a chart editor where you can change the type of chart/colors/year range etc. I convert datatable to dataview and that I use in wrapper class but this shouldn't be a problem. Because settings are always the same, aren't they?

Comment: The only problem is that this isn't working with viewWindow.min option https://jsfiddle.net/8rdc4u1L/35/

Comment: So there is no another solution with using only viewWindow option, isn't there? I wanted to avoid to filter dataTable manually.

Comment: no other option i can think of, but shouldn't need to manually filter to use `ticks`, don't have to use `getDistinctValues` to fill...